# PySpark- how to select Max value compared to a parameter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `Max` date from a column `DateCol`, that is less than a variable `run_date`.

For example from this input table below, I want to compare the `DateCol` with a variable `runtime`. Suppose `run_time= '2022-03-05'`, I'd like to select the third row, as that's where the Max value is, and `DateCol<='2022-03-05'` How can this be done? Many thanks.

```
+---+---+------+
| ID|    DateCol |
+---+---+-------
|1. |'2022-03-01'|
|2  |'2022-03-03'|
|3. |'2022-03-04'|
|4. |'2022-03-06'|
+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a filter based on `run_time` then sort by date and get the max record.

```py
run_time= '2022-03-05'

(df
    .where(F.col('DateCol') <= run_time)
    .orderBy(F.desc('DateCol'))
    .limit(1)
    .show()
)

+---+----------+
| ID|   DateCol|
+---+----------+
|  3|2022-03-04|
+---+----------+
```